# How can I launch the appstore from my web app in smart tv?

Tags: angular, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

Launch the app store for smart TV tizen

I am trying to launch the app store from my current tizen TV application. I am using angular and making my app a web aplication. Right now I want to create a dialog in case there is a new version in store send them to store and upgrade. I found that can be done using the application controls of tizen but I can find a way to use that in angular.

How can I launch the app store from my smart TV web app?

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386635/5224957

Answer (score 0):

Do not open to 3rd party to run the App Store on Web.

It is possible to use Application Control, but it does not disclose the App Store ID.

TV update app automatically when power on/off

Comment: But what it will happend if the TV has the auto update "off"? The thing is I want that if there is a new version in store and the one installed is diferent send the user to the store to update? Do you know how to use the app control with javascript web api?